# Want to find sales territory for each group

Tags: sql-server

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ku2eg.jpg)
This image contain the final output of sales territory

I have done this by using 6 unions as code given below:

```
select SalesTerritoryGroup,SalesTerritoryRegion='',Sum(SalesAmount) as TotalSales from DimSalesTerritory A
right join FactInternetSales B
on B.SalesTerritoryKey=A.SalesTerritoryKey
group by SalesTerritoryGroup
having SalesTerritoryGroup in('North America')

Union All

select SalesTerritoryGroup='' ,SalesTerritoryRegion,Sum(SalesAmount) as TotalSales from DimSalesTerritory A
right join FactInternetSales B
on B.SalesTerritoryKey=A.SalesTerritoryKey
where SalesTerritoryGroup in ('North America')
group by SalesTerritoryRegion,SalesTerritoryGroup

Union all

select SalesTerritoryGroup,SalesTerritoryRegion='',Sum(SalesAmount) as TotalSales from DimSalesTerritory A
right join FactInternetSales B
on B.SalesTerritoryKey=A.SalesTerritoryKey
group by SalesTerritoryGroup
having SalesTerritoryGroup in('Europe')

Union all

select SalesTerritoryGroup='' ,SalesTerritoryRegion,Sum(SalesAmount) as TotalSales from DimSalesTerritory A
right join FactInternetSales B
on B.SalesTerritoryKey=A.SalesTerritoryKey
where SalesTerritoryGroup in ('Europe')
group by SalesTerritoryRegion,SalesTerritoryGroup

Union all

select SalesTerritoryGroup,SalesTerritoryRegion='',Sum(SalesAmount) as TotalSales from DimSalesTerritory A
right join FactInternetSales B
on B.SalesTerritoryKey=A.SalesTerritoryKey
group by SalesTerritoryGroup
having SalesTerritoryGroup in('Pacific')

Union all

select SalesTerritoryGroup='' ,SalesTerritoryRegion,Sum(SalesAmount) as TotalSales from DimSalesTerritory A
right join FactInternetSales B
on B.SalesTerritoryKey=A.SalesTerritoryKey
where SalesTerritoryGroup in ('Pacific')
group by SalesTerritoryRegion,SalesTerritoryGroup

Union all 

select SalesTerritoryGroup='Grand Total',SalesTerritoryRegion='',Sum(SalesAmount) as TotalSales from DimSalesTerritory A
right join FactInternetSales B
on B.SalesTerritoryKey=A.SalesTerritoryKey
Where SalesTerritoryGroup in ('Pacific','Europe','North America')
```

But how to get the same result using three unions instead of six?

Comment: What you *really* want to use is a `GROUP BY` clause. Also, a clause like `having SalesTerritoryGroup in('Pacific')` doesn't make a lot of sense; the `HAVING` is for aggregation expressions, but yours contain none. That should be in the `WHERE`. Finally "A" is for "SalesTerritory" and "B" is for "InternetSales"? Where is there a "b" in "InternetSales"? Use *good* aliasing. [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: Looks like you are implementing `GROUP BY WITH ROLL UP` yourself using `UNION ALL`

Comment: There are two tables DimSalesTerritory As A and FactInternetSales AS B.

Comment: Yes, But i want to do the same with using only three unions. what will be the query for this?